# Chart data displays on the console.log but not on the page (Using Axios/Vue)

Tags: javascript, axios, chart.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to use axios to get data for my Chart but I couldn't know how to make it appear on the canvas, i can see the values on the console.log as below

[Console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtIC4.png),
I'm not too sure what is happening, here's my code :

```
   mounted(){
  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
  let myData = [];
 const myChart = new Chart(ctx,
   {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
   labels: [....],
    datasets: [{
        data: this.myData,
        backgroundColor: [  ['blue']],
                 }] },
      options: {.....}
           });
           myChart;
```

here's the methode:

```
created: function(){
 this.getData();} ,
methods: {
getData : function(){
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/Chart/chartjs')
  .then(resp => {this.myData = resp.data
  console.log(resp.data); }) }
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is related to the [reactivity fundamentals](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#declaring-reactive-state) of VueJS. As you are declaring a local variable in the mounted method and trying to access the property myData on *this* without declaring it in the component, VueJS will not update the UI.

The way you presented your code, I'll assume that you are using VueJS3 with the Options API.

To have a reactive component, you need to declare a reactive state.  This is usually done before the mounted() method.

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            myData: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
    ...
```

Afterward, in your mounted and getData methods, instead of declaring myData, you need to use `this.myData`.  VueJS will take care of the reactivity.

Also, I noticed that you are trying to access the DOM directly. This is not a usual or recommended in VueJS.  You should use a bind to make sure your properties are updated correctly.

Comment: I managed to maintain the reactivity but still doesn't work, it may has something to do maybe with what you mentioned about the direct DOM access, can you give me more details ? Thank you

Comment: One of the primary rules with VueJS is never directly modify the DOM.  VueJS is build to do it. 

If you look at the [Introduction in the Getting Started guide](https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#what-is-vue) you will notice that there's no script at all to modify the DOM. As the variable `count` is in the `data()` method, VueJS will observe all changes you do to the variable.

In the `Template` section, the variable `count` is binded using {{ }}.  That refers directly to the `count` in the `data()` method.